# How to pass file path as arguments using ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I am trying to run an `.exe` file and want to give file path as arguments, but I am getting an invalid command exception.
Below is the command, which is working

```
   C:\XX\win64\xxx.exe --input "xxx.yy" --output "xxx.zz" --license "123"
```

Below is the Java code I am trying to use to run it

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("C:\XX\win64\xxx.exe", "--input \"xxx.yy\"",
    "--output \"xxx.zz\"", "\--license \"123\" ").start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it was a typo..Sorry

Comment: Also the escape chars need escaping

Comment: Please include your stack trace in your question. Also, you haven't escaped the backslashes in your first argument - is that another question typo? If not, that may be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you copied the snippet from your code, it might be the third argument not being wrapped in double quotes.

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\XX\\win64\\xxx.exe","--input \"xxx.yy\"",
"--output \"xxx.zz\"" ,"\--license \"123\" ").start();
```

Comment: Thanks Dragan... but it was a typo...sorry